# Input of integer in the range of 10^1000

Tags: c++, c, biginteger

Is it possible to take an input of range greater than what C/C++ provides? Is it possible to accept an input range greater than that of unsigned long long and even larger up to the range of 10^1000?
If it is possible in C/C++, please answer how it can be done, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible with a string or a big integer that supports that.

Comment: Use `std::string`/`std::vector<char>` or a specific library ?

Comment: `unsigned long long` can't take 10^1000 as a input!

Comment: There is no data type to hold such value. However you can store them into vector of character and then write your own manipulation functions.

Comment: @Sathish, `log10(2⁶⁴)` is 19. That's nowhere near enough. Your `unsigned long long` would have to be pretty darn wide.

Comment: @chiris is it possible to take 10^1000 as a input `unsigned long long`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no bigint in C or C++, however library like this one can provide it: https://code.google.com/p/infint/

Comment: I don't think "simulate" is the proper verb here. It *provides* bigint functionality.

Comment: Lol.., `C+++`? You probably want to write `C++`

Comment: @CollioTV
Thanks but can you guide me how to set this header file named InfInt.h for my compiler, i am using codeblocks, and while i paste this header file inside this (C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include) path, the compiler still fails to identify the header file.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i'm not develloping on codeblocks... i don't really know how to import over library on this ide! @Jongware i'm sorry, english isn't my native language so id make mistake like this oftenly

Comment: No problem at all, and absolutely no need to apologize! We still understood what you meant. As far as English goes, "practice, practice, practice", and I consider SO a good place to do so! (You might find your answers may be improved 'silently', where someone edited your post. In this case I thought it wise to point out the difference; "simulate" is a valid term in programming, but it means something else.)

Answer (score 4):

Input into a string. Then convert the string into the desired type.

If you use a library that provides types for large integers, such a library might also offer input functions.